# MS ACCESS VBA, working days function incl. holiday when faling on weekend

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

When deploying MSDN function for calculating working days, beside a problem with date formatting I found an issue with Holiday count.

Calculation is correct, but only if Holiday is on working day. If it is on a saturday or sunday, it also substract it and produce a false result. 
[illustration of a false reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsypH.jpg)

A Function for Workdays:

```
Public Function Workdays(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date, Optional ByRef strHolidays As String = "Holidays") As Integer
On Error GoTo Workdays_Error
Dim nWeekdays, nHolidays As Integer
Dim strWhere As String

startDate = DateValue(startDate)
endDate = DateValue(endDate)
nWeekdays = Weekdays(startDate, endDate)

If nWeekdays = -1 Then
    Workdays = -1
    GoTo Workdays_Exit
End If

strWhere = "[Holiday] >= #" & Format(startDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND [Holiday] <= #" & Format(endDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
nHolidays = DCount(Expr:="[Holiday]", Domain:=strHolidays, Criteria:=strWhere)
Workdays = nWeekdays - nHolidays

Workdays_Exit:
    Exit Function
    Resume Workdays_Exit

End Function
```

And here is a function for calculating weekdays:

```
Public Function Weekdays(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date) As Integer
' Returns the number of weekdays in the period from startDate
' to endDate inclusive. Returns -1 if an error occurs.

On Error GoTo Weekdays_Error
Const ncNumberOfWeekendDays As Integer = 2 'The number of weekend days per week.
Dim varDays As Variant                  'The number of days inclusive.
Dim varWeekendDays As Variant     'The number of weekend days.
Dim dtmX As Date                          'Temporary storage for datetime.

' If the end date is earlier, swap the dates.
If endDate < startDate Then
    dtmX = startDate
    startDate = endDate
    endDate = dtmX
End If

' Calculate the number of days inclusive (+ 1 is to add back startDate).
varDays = DateDiff(Interval:="d", date1:=startDate, date2:=endDate) + 1

' Calculate the number of weekend days.
varWeekendDays = (DateDiff(Interval:="ww", date1:=startDate, date2:=endDate) _
    * ncNumberOfWeekendDays) + IIf(DatePart(Interval:="w", _
    Date:=startDate) = vbSunday, 1, 0) + IIf(DatePart(Interval:="w", Date:=endDate) = vbSaturday, 1, 0)

' Calculate the number of weekdays.
Weekdays = (varDays - varWeekendDays)

Weekdays_Exit:
    Exit Function

Weekdays_Error:
    Weekdays = -1
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Weekdays"
    Resume Weekdays_Exit
```

Please advise how to ignore holiday if holiday = 1 or holiday = 7.
Plus, in extended period of time, there could be more than one holidays, falling or not on weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without delving into your code, I'd suggest doing a count of holidays in your holiday table that fall on weekends and which also fall inside the range of days you are considering. Subtract that total from an (I presume) otherwise correctly calculated total and you should have the proper adjustment taking weekend holidays into account.

Comment: You just gave me an idea to create a querry with new field DayNum: Weekday([holidays]![Holiday]) which is filtered <7 And >1. This works fine so far, but I would like to (learn how to) do it within a VBA.

Comment: Yes, my proposed solution would be done from within VBA. A couple well-designed DCount() calls with results stored to integers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler just to loop the dates and count:

```
Public Function DateDiffWorkdays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booWorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Long

'   Calculates the count of workdays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    Dim aHolidays() As Date

    Dim lngDiff     As Long
    Dim lngSign     As Long
    Dim lngHoliday  As Long

    lngSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2))
    If lngSign <> 0 Then
        If booWorkOnHolidays = True Then
            ' Holidays are workdays.
        Else
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
            aHolidays = GetHolidays(datDate1, datDate2)
        End If

        Do Until DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) = 0
            Select Case Weekday(datDate1)
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    ' Skip weekend.
                Case Else
                    ' Check for holidays to skip.
                    ' Ignore error when using LBound and UBound on an unassigned array.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For lngHoliday = LBound(aHolidays) To UBound(aHolidays)
                        If Err.Number > 0 Then
                            ' No holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
                        ElseIf DateDiff("d", datDate1, aHolidays(lngHoliday)) = 0 Then
                            ' This datDate1 hits a holiday.
                            ' Subtract one day before adding one after the loop.
                            lngDiff = lngDiff - lngSign
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    lngDiff = lngDiff + lngSign
            End Select
            datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngSign, datDate1)
        Loop
    End If

    DateDiffWorkdays = lngDiff

End Function
```

and the holidays function:

```
Public Function GetHolidays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booDesc As Boolean) _
    As Date()

'   Finds the count of holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   The holidays are returned as an array of dates.
'   DAO objects are declared static to speed up repeated calls with identical date parameters.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' The table that holds the holidays.
    Const cstrTable             As String = "tblHoliday"
    ' The field of the table that holds the dates of the holidays.
    Const cstrField             As String = "HolidayDate"
    ' Constants for the arrays.
    Const clngDimRecordCount    As Long = 2
    Const clngDimFieldOne       As Long = 0

    Static dbs              As DAO.Database
    Static rst              As DAO.Recordset

    Static datDate1Last     As Date
    Static datDate2Last     As Date

    Dim adatDays()  As Date
    Dim avarDays    As Variant

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strDate1    As String
    Dim strDate2    As String
    Dim strOrder    As String
    Dim lngDays     As Long

    If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate1Last) <> 0 Or DateDiff("d", datDate2, datDate2Last) <> 0 Then
        ' datDate1 or datDate2 has changed since the last call.
        strDate1 = Format(datDate1, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strDate2 = Format(datDate2, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strOrder = Format(booDesc, "\A\s\c;\D\e\s\c")

        strSQL = "Select " & cstrField & " From " & cstrTable & " " & _
            "Where " & cstrField & " Between " & strDate1 & " And " & strDate2 & " " & _
            "Order By 1 " & strOrder

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        ' Save the current set of date parameters.
        datDate1Last = datDate1
        datDate2Last = datDate2
    End If

    lngDays = rst.RecordCount
    If lngDays = 0 Then
        ' Leave adatDays() as an unassigned array.
    Else
        ReDim adatDays(lngDays - 1)
        ' As repeated calls may happen, do a movefirst.
        rst.MoveFirst
        avarDays = rst.GetRows(lngDays)
        ' rst is now positioned at the last record.
        For lngDays = LBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount) To UBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount)
            adatDays(lngDays) = avarDays(clngDimFieldOne, lngDays)
        Next
    End If

    ' DAO objects are static.
    ' Set rst = Nothing
    ' Set dbs = Nothing

    GetHolidays = adatDays()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to get the number of working days (excluding public holidays) between two dates.

It requires a table named **tbHolidays** with a single field named **_Date** which holds the public holidays.

```
Public Function WorkingDaysInDateRange(ByVal DateFrom As Date, _
                                       ByVal DateTo As Date, _
                                       Optional ByVal includeStartDate As Long = 0) As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    'Calculate the number of days
    Dim lngTotalDays As Long
        lngTotalDays = DateDiff("y", DateFrom, DateTo) + includeStartDate

    'Calculate the number of weekend days.
    Dim lngWeekendDays As Long
        lngWeekendDays = (DateDiff("ww", DateFrom, DateTo) * 2) + _
                          IIf(DatePart("w", DateFrom) = vbSunday, 1, 0) + _
                          IIf(DatePart("w", DateTo) = vbSaturday, 1, 0)

    'Get Non working days count from tbHolidays excluding weekends
    Dim lngHolidays As Long
        lngHolidays = DCount("[_Date]", "tbHolidays", _
                             StringFormat("[_Date] Between #{0}# AND #{1}# AND Weekday([_Date]) Not In ({2}, {3})", Format(DateFrom, "mm/dd/yyyy"), _
                                                                                                                    Format(DateTo, "mm/dd/yyyy"), _
                                                                                                                    vbSaturday, vbSunday))
    Dim lngWrkDays As Long
        lngWrkDays = lngTotalDays - (lngWeekendDays + lngHolidays)

    'Return
    WorkingDaysInDateRange = lngWrkDays

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

---

The helper **StringFormat** function:

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal Item As String, ParamArray args() As Variant) As String

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        Item = Replace(Item, "{" & idx & "}", args(idx))
    Next idx

    StringFormat = Item
End Function
```